# Script to determine if apparent Image files are real Image files

Tags: shell-script, files, images

I would like to create a shell script that will check to make sure all files in a directory that appear superficially to be image files (e.g. have typical image file extensions like .jpg, .bmp etc.) are actually image files.

We recently had an issue where a hacker was able to generate a file in a directory and mask it as a .jpg file. I would like to create a shell script to check all files in the directory to make sure they are real jpg, gif or png files.

Comment: Use `file *` to check file types

Comment: Checking file contents sounds like a bad solution to a security problem. What happened after the attacker created their non-JPEG .jpg file? Could there be a way of preventing them from doing the part that is actually harmful?

Comment: What if you just configure your web server to not execute any code in the upload directory ? That way attacker can upload malware all day long, but nothing will be executed.

Comment: The upload directory is not the problem, it was where they saved the file.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but given the background of the issue you may find this useful.
https://github.com/maxlabelle/WebMalwareScanner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to be very careful about using `file` in a circumstance where you give it completely untrusted input. For instance, RHEL 5 `file` will identify this:

```
GIF87a
<?php
echo "Hello from PHP!\n";
?>
```

As "GIF image data, version 87a, 15370 x 28735".  The PHP interpreter has no trouble executing that input. That lack of trouble is the basis for "[local file inclusion](http://www.exploit-db.com/download_pdf/13678/)" (LFI) problems.

Second, `file` (and even `strings`) actually parse input files to tell you what you want to know. These [parsers are complicated](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html) and [have problems](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-9620).

I'm going to suggest the `identify` command out of the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite. It isn't fooled by my simple example above, and it only parses image files correctly, so it should be less prone to security flaws than `file`.

Comment: See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189367/87770) for an implementation using ImageMagick `identify` … and two examples of how to beat it.

Answer (score 8):

As a quick first pass, the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command can quickly detect image headers:

```
if file "$FILE" |grep -qE 'image|bitmap'; then
  echo "File '$FILE' has the headers of an image"
fi
```

(The second alternation for `bitmap` is needed if you want to recognize [Windows BMP files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) since libmagic does not use the word "image" to describe bitmap images.)

**However**, we can trick `file` with the PHP-based fake image from [Bruce Ediger's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189364/script-to-determine-if-files-are-images/189373#189373):

```
$ echo 'GIF87a<?php echo "Hello from PHP!"; ?>' > fake.gif
$ file fake.gif && echo image detected || echo no image detected
fake.gif: GIF image data, version 87a, 16188 x 26736
image detected
```

### Using Imagemagick identify

The [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) suite has an [identify](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) script with a CLI frontend that will return some metadata on a given image.  It fails when the expected metadata is not present, so it is ideal for this purpose:

```
$ identify fake.gif && echo image detected || echo no image detected
identify-im6.q16: negative or zero image size `fake.gif' @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1402.
no image detected
```

For faster scanning of a large collection of files, I recommend putting both together:

```
if file "$FILE" |grep -qE 'image|bitmap' \
&& ! identify "$FILE" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "File '$FILE' is a fake image!"
fi
```

(This redirects the output of `identify` into oblivion since we only care about whether it was able to complete successfully, which is captured by its exit code.)

### Even this can still be tricked

The following example uses a simple 1x1 white GIF with the same PHP code added to the end.  I don't know PHP and I'm not sure this will actually run, but since PHP is a template language that prints the literal "text" to anything outside its `<?php … ?>` tag, I assume that this will run the given code as-is, with merely some garbage before the payload.

```
$ { echo 'R0lGODdhAQABAIAAAP///////ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBAD'
    echo 's8P3BocCBlY2hvICJIZWxsbyBmcm9tIFBIUCEiOyA/Pgo='
  } | base64 -d > fake2.gif
$ strings fake2.gif
GIF87a
;<?php echo "Hello from PHP!"; ?>
$ file fake2.gif
fake2.gif: GIF image data, version 87a, 1 x 1
$ identify fake2.gif
fake2.gif GIF 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 68B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

This can also be done with a GIF comment to be fully valid as an image:

```
$ hd fake3.gif
00000000  47 49 46 38 39 61 01 00  01 00 80 00 00 ff ff ff  |GIF89a..........|
00000010  ff ff ff 21 fe 20 3c 3f  70 68 70 20 65 63 68 6f  |...!. <?php echo|
00000020  20 22 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20  66 72 6f 6d 20 50 48 50  | "Hello from PHP|
00000030  21 22 3b 20 3f 3e 00 2c  00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00  |!"; ?>.,........|
00000040  00 02 02 44 01 00 3b                              |...D..;|
00000047
```

I've picked on GIF and taken advantage of its comment system, but just concatenating a payload after any image should also work to bypass this detection technique.  It's merely harder than fooling `file` and (depending on the implementation) it *might* leave some evidence behind (the garbage from the image).

Comment: There is just one little problem. BMP files: `1.bmp:  PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 1345 x 620 x 24`. Other files like .jpeg, .png, .tif and .rgb will have the `image data` string on the `file` command return.

Comment: @nwildner: brentwpeterson only mentioned jpg, gif or png.

Comment: @nwildner, .bmp is easily added.  See my revision above.  IIRC, it's the only image format that doesn't have the word "image" in its libmagic description.

Comment: Great add, even with .bmp not being part of the scope :).  `grep 'image\|bitmap'` shall work too.

Comment: honest question, why does this have no upvotes? the `file` syntax is obviously the way to go

Comment: @Blauhirn – File magic is great, but only examines the first few characters of each file and can therefore be tricked.  That's the whole point of the question.  My answer uses it as a pre-filter and then runs *supposed* images through imagemagick's `identify` in order to determine whether it has more expected image metadata.  This can be tricked too, but it's harder to do.

Comment: @AdamKatz is there a way to check if `identify` is being tricked, like to somehow check that the image is invalid like your last example shows?

Comment: @Lance – Yes. If you have a different way to detect an invalid image, you could compare its output to `identify` the same way I did with `identify` to find non-images identified with `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the commands put together by @Adam Katz, I found that my system always failed because the `-q` option used to suppress the output from grep made it always give a return code of zero. Removing this allows it to work OK, but it means that the output of the identify command is strewn across the screen.

I am using GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and GNU grep 3.7, which ship with Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS by default.

My solution works the same way as Adams, running the necessary commands from within the test.

```
[[ ( $(file "$file" | grep -E 'image|bitmap') != ""  ) \
&& ( $(identify $file | grep error) -eq 0 ) ]] \
&& echo "File $file appears to be an image" \
|| echo "File $file appears to be a fake"
```

I hope this helps someone in the same way that Adam's post helped me.